# Express API with JWT returns "Unauthorized: Invalid Algorithm error"

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, superagent, express-jwt

I've written a simple React app, following the instructions of a slightly out of date tutorial that is meant to display a list of contacts in the sidebar with individual contact data displayed in an index component but only if you have been authenticated by logging into an Auth0 component and have a JSON Web Token kept in local storage. I have confirmed that I am logged in and have the token. Everything up to this point is working fine.

The problem begins when I click on a contact in the sidebar to view that contact's data, which comes down from a pretty basic API set up with Express. I've been using Postman to troubleshoot since the only error I get from app is "401: Unauthorized"

When I hit my endpoint, suppling an Authorization header with "Bearer [JWT_VALUE_HERE]" Postman responds with "UnauthorizedError: invalid algorithm"

The full output

```
UnauthorizedError: invalid algorithm
            
    at /Users/Arkham/Documents/Web/eldrac/react-auth-server/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:102:22
            
    at /Users/Arkham/Documents/Web/eldrac/react-auth-server/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:27:18
            
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
            
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

I've done a bit of googling and tweaked my Auth0 client settings, specifically the Algorithm settings but no matter what I set it to (my options are RS256 and HS256), it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm dying to get past this.

I use Superagent to make my request

```
getContact: (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request
        .get(url)
        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + AuthStore.getJwt())
        .end((err, response) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve(JSON.parse(response.text));
        })
    });
  }
```

Which seems to be working. I have confirmed that the url is correct and that AuthStore.getJwt() are supplying the correct parameters.

Comment: Bryan - did you see my answer - any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide much information necessary to diagnose the issue - First of all, you should be sending a JWT Access token to the API, not your Id Token.

**Upfront questions:**

- Do you have an API defined in the Auth0 Dashboard?
- When you authenticate, are you using an audience parameter?  It is
  likely that the Access Token is using RS256. Remember for an access
  token and Resource API, it is the API that controls the algorithm,
  not the Client.
- What algorithm is your API using to verify the token?
- Presumably, the `url` in your code snippet is something like
  `http://localhost:3001/myendpoint`?

Take your token, and paste it at https://jwt.io to see what the algorithm used is. Compare that with what is being used to verify the token.

Shall update my answer here as you give more information - please use comments section for this answer.